# oversized elf generation for powerpc using csgnu toolchain

Tags: gcc, powerpc

i am compiling a rtos for mpc56xx platform where 1MB flash is at 0x00 and i am putting my vector table at 0xe0000 address. problem is that gcc compiles an elf which contains abstract zeros in between my end of flash sections and start of my exception table. the result is that my elf has increased uselessly to a huge size not fitting in my flash.

if i just place my table within flash as well, elf is good

how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This seem an issue related to your linker command file (lcf). Can you post here the relevant portion of it?

Also, which version of ld are you using?

If you are using ". = 0xe000" syntax in your lcf, this might be the problem. Rather try to declare a separate output section, e.g.:

```
.exception_vectors:
{
    exception_vectors.o (.text)
} > exception_vectors_region
```

where yout MEMORY part contains:

```
exception_vectors_region : org = 0x000e0000, len = 0x1000
```